# exporting objects in node.js modules

Tags: node.js

I have a node 'class' defined in a separate file as follows:

```
function Node_class(){
 //code
}

Node_class.prototype = {

    function _1 : function(){
      //code
    }

};

module.exports.Node_class= Node_class;
```

now when I want to create a new instance of Node_class in a separate file so I did the following:

```
var node_object = new require('./node_class').Node_class();
node_object.function_1();//is not defined
```

node_object.function_1() is not defined in the separate file for some reason. Can someone help me export this node 'class' properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are causing this. First, there's a space where there shouldn't be here:

```
function _1 : function(){
```

It's probably just a typo, but it should be:

```
function_1 : function(){
```

Second, if you're going to call `new` on `require('./node_class').Node_class` you need to wrap it in parenthesis:

```
var node_object = new (require('./node_class').Node_class)();
```

Or, alternatively, you could do:

```
var Node_class = require('./node_class').Node_class;
var node_object = new Node_class();
```